# Is it Bad Practice to use HTML Styling in Java Swing Elements?

Tags: java, swing

It is considered bad practice to style Swing elements using HTML?

As an example, if I want to make a label bigger and red just once, I have two options:

Either using API calls:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("This is a title");  
label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(18));  
label.setForeground(Color.red);
```

Or by using HTML:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><font size='4' color='#ff0000'>This is a title");
```

In addition, the *HTML way* allows me to emphasise one word instead of a whole label, and other such uses.

What are the drawbacks of using HTML? Is it more expensive? And is formatting not guaranteed on all JREs?

Comment: Who told you it was bad practice to use HTML styling in Swing?  Shame on them.  It's easily one of the best ways to provided extended rendering to many of the Swing Components.  I personally use this technique when rendering complex tool tips, allows me to display tables and images among other things

Comment: I generally agree with you. Nobody told me that I shouldn't use it, but it just feels a little "dirty"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, it is not bad or good practice to use HTML syntax in the Swing JComponents
2. Today, Java supports HTML 3.2 and there is reduced support for certain CSS attributes
3. JTextPane and  JEditorPane support adding and positioning JComponents using HTML syntax

Comment: @Redandwhite I'm not sure in this moment if Icons by A*d*o*b*e aren't ..., call it free for use and distri****, maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

[Using `<font>` is bad](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlintermediate/badtags/) even in html.  And using objects to customize font color, size etc is lot of work in big applications.

Fortunately, javaFX 2 is out.  With it you can use CSS to deal with these kinds of things : 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/documentation/index.html

Comment: I would agree that using the Font tag is bad when producing HTML, but considering we only have support for HTML 3.2 and limited CSS support, what choice do we have in this case - if we want to use Swing and not JavaFX

Comment: Then I would recommed to use the Font object.  It's more work but easier to reuse and maintain (ie, change font of a lot of labels, buttons etc, in one touch).

Comment: If I use the Font object, it's a little heavy to use it in a large application. I typically use a combination of the two methods. However, while I abhor the use of <font> when writing normal HTML, I don't see the problem when using it in such a specific use case, where compatibility is usually guaranteed